# iPhone voice memos to windows pc

Tags: windows-10, iphone

I am trying to get a voice memo from my iPhone into my windows PC. My iPhone is 4s and i am running windows 10. Is it possible to do so? I have tried [this](https://www.imobie.com/support/transfer-voice-memos-from-iphone-to-computer.htm) software but it is not detecting my phone.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it is possible. Just download [Apple iTunes for Window](http://www.apple.com/dk/itunes/download/)

If you don't want to use iTunes you can just share it directly from your phone by mail. Open Voice Memos, Select your track and tap "Share" and pick mail.

Answer (score 1):

If your voice memo's are too big for e-mail, then you can create a dropbox, or google drive account and upload them to there.

Comment: Will it then be able to be downloaded and play on there windows os?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Yes! It downloads in m4a format which can be played with VLC.